# Help with copying and pasting smart objects from indesign to photoshop (blank pixels at edge of objects)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, vector, smartobject, copy-and-paste

So im copying vectors from indesign to photoshop (for a mockup) and when I paste some things, there is a blank space at the edge of the vector in photoshop. in the indesign document, I've checked that there are no random objects/boxes outside of what i'm copying and i've made sure to fit content to frame for the objects too but i don't know why there is still a blank space at the edge of the smart object when i copy and paste objects from indesign to photoshop.
do you know why, and is there a fix for this?..

screens for reference:

this is how it looks in indesign:
[image: indesign object]

and then this is how it looks when pasted in photoshop (see the blank pixels at the top edge)

[image: and then how it looks when pasted in photoshop]

please help with this. thank you <333

Comment: If youbselect and move individual elements one at a time, you may discover the rogue element.

Answer (score 2):

I know you already checked, but there is one reason for this and you guessed it: something does actually exist there outside the green object. I suggest you do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> in InDesign and see if the selection box only includes the green object and whatever is inside. My guess is this will reveal you have a hanging tiny object outside the green object. If that doesn't work, try deleting all your guides before copy pasting. The first horizontal guide looks purple, which means its probably selected, and that may also be a reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

Grouping items in Indesign resolves this issue but I still have similar issues with single text boxes being pasted into PS with unwanted white space?